# how to set GIF as wallpaper using WallpaperManager

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

How to set GIF in wallpaper in WallpaperManager in android .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please describe your problem in more detail. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
Intent i = new Intent();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

String p = HypercaneWallpaperService.class.getPackage().getName();
String c = HypercaneWallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();        
i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(p, c));
}
else{
i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
}
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```